# How to have multiple origin address for shipping in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using Magento1.7.0.2. I want to have more than one shipping origin address for my site since ordered items are sent from different Warehouses depends upon the products.Please suggest if there is any extension which solves my problem.
Thanks in Advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Multi-Warehouse extension. It can solve your problem: http://innoexts.com/promotion/multi-warehouse/

Comment: Can you give more details about the extension? Single link answers are not really appreciated on SO. (unless someone asks for a single link)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are, but dropshipping extensions tend to be on the pricey side (and you will realise why when you see the code base and the work that goes into them).

I'd be interested to see if anyone posts an answer for a cheap dropshipping module that they would recommend and that works well.  I would be getting the client to stump up for one of these two though;

http://www.unirgy.com/products/udropship/

http://www.webshopapps.com/uk/shipping/dropship.html