# what is the use of Shipping Settings in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, shipping-address

what is the use of  Shipping Settings in magento. What & how it works? What happen with country and state selected from here? Does it make any restriction is yes then where it make?

System->configuration->sales->Shipping Settings

Answer (score 1):

From Magento documentation:

> The Shipping Settings establish the point of origin for all shipments made from your store or warehouse, and your preference for managing orders that are shipped to multiple addresses. The point of origin determines the tax rate that is used for products sold from the store.

Comment: how its calculate? we use table rate for enter shipment charge via excel)? how to point multiple store

Comment: To see the calculation options, I suggest you look into System -> Configuration -> Tax -> Calculation. To see multiple shipping origins I suggest you look at this post: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/how-to-have-multiple-origin-address-for-shipping-in-magento-1-7-0-2